# Query data in ViewModel that doesn't need to be displayed in Activity

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I'm using MVVM [architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) by Android. For information that is going to be displayed in the `View` (`Activity`), they recommend to expose LiveData from `ViewModel`. The `Observers` in the Activity will consume that data and react to their changes.

But I don't know what happens when you want to fetch information (maybe other tables in your database) that you need to do some business validation for example. You definitely don't want to display that information in the UI, so it doesn't make sense to include Observers in the Activity for that.

It is possible to use `observeForever` in the ViewModel, so you can consume LiveData from Repository that you don't need to display in the Activity. However, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) says that ViewModel should noy contain observers to LiveData.

I cannot find any good example that deals with this situation so far.

**EXAMPLE**

I have one MainActivity that will create a `Tournament` record, which contains the Integer "numberOfRounds", selected by the user on the screen.

Now, in Activity `PairingsView`, I display the following `AlertDialog` when the user clicks the "finish current Round" button:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.continues, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    if (mViewModel.hasNextRond()) {
                        mViewModel.calculateNewPairings();
                    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
public boolean hasNextRound() {
    return currentRound <= numberOfRounds;
}
```

Here, I've access to `currentRound` value, since I exposed `Round` table information in `PairingsView`. But I also need to know the `numberOfRounds` to check if I must generate pairings for next round. This value is stored in `Tournament` table, and I don't need to display any information from that table in my View, so I think I shouldn't include an Observer for it.

Comment: Why is your ViewModel doing anything *not* associated with the UI? Can you share a code example of where you'd find this necessary?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hi, I've added a simplified example of my code, that I think it exposes the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `observeForever` in the ViewModel but you should remove the observer in `onCleared` method of ViewModel in order to prevent from memory leaking